# Pycharm autocompletion hints for variables

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I Pycharm I can hint the IDE for the variable type in a method like this:

```
def __init__(self, filepath=None):
    """
    Init a new instance
    :param str filepath: optional full path to file
    """
```

I'm trying to do the same for a single variable (could be a variable inside a module or a class), so the IDE will know what type of data should be stored in that variable

```
current_credentials = None
""":type CredentialsClass the current credentials class"""
```

but it doesn't help the IDE..

how can I do it properly ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is slightly different here.

On PyCharm 3.4.1 (as for me) the feature works well for the following example code:

```
x = None
""" :type x: str """

class C:
    """ :type v: str """
    v = None
```

[How it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp3Db.png)

Also, if you use your own types, and type definition is placed outside the current file, don't forget to import it or provide a scoped name.